# elemental powers in D4

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I have a dihedral group $G = D4 =\{e,f,g,fg,f^2,f^2g,f^3,f^3g\}$ and a subgroup $H = \{e,f^2g\}$

I found the right and left cosets (left cosets specifically) using the fact that $f^4=e$. Why is this fact true?

Does it have anything to do with $x^(|G|) = e$ since $4$ divides $8$? If that's true, can we also say $f^8 = e$?

Comment: Which fact is true? Make the question more clear, please

Comment: What is your definition of *dihedral group*?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your question is: why is $f^4=e$, then its just a case of if $f$ represents a $90^{\circ}$ clockwise rotation, then $f^4=ffff$ or four 90 degrees rotations, that is a 360 degrees rotation which is the same as performing $e$ as youre back to where you started from.

it should then be clear that $f^8=e$ also.